How do I fix this? (Torn paint)
Stupidly attached an adhesive hook to the bathroom wall and tore the paint trying to take it off.
https://imgur.com/a/dXLOqoh
Unfortunately the paint predates us as owners of the home, so I don’t know the exact shade.
Is there any way to mitigate without repainting the entire bathroom?

Cut the hanging part off carefully. Repair the scar with spackle.  Take the pait you cut off to the hardware store/ paint store and ask them to match it and hope for the best.  With matching paint ,you still may need to paint from one corner to the next and top to bottom.

Cut the loose paint off with something like a razor blade.
Sand the edges to feather them.  Might need a bit of drywall mud if deeper.
A paint store might be able to match the colour, but might still stand out.
If it stands out too much for you till repainting, Either covering it(picture/mirror) or make it a design feature, paint it blue(or whatever) and repeat in a pattern, maybe blue dots around that receptacle.
